# Simple rule checking behaviour in JES?

Tags: function, jes

How can we implement simple rule-checking behaviours in JES? Can you write a simple JES function that asks the user to enter a number between 0 and 9 then prints out the corresponding English word (e.g. 0 is “zero”, 1 is “one”, etc.)?

This is a question i have been asked for a practice tutorial but im struggling and need some help with !

Answer (score 0):

if statements

```
if x equals x
    print "yay"
```